# echo {Z..A}; out {Z..A};Why?

Tags: zsh, brace-expansion

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I am reading this book "The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction" and practicing the code. That's fun, but I have trouble in Chapter 8:

```
➜  ~ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
➜  ~ echo {z..a}
{z..a}
➜  ~ echo {Z..A}
{Z..A}
➜  ~ echo {a..z}
{a..z}
➜  ~
```

I can't get a range of letters. Why? How do I fix it? My shell is oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *ksh* (and *bash*) feature and may not be in *your* shell, e.g., *dash* (default shell used in Debian/Ubuntu).

To see the difference, try

```
bash -c "echo {a..z}"
dash -c "echo {a..z}"
```

The default `/bin/sh` with Debian points to `dash`.  But if you happen to be running in a bash shell, you will see the sequences expanded as you expect.  Scripts beginning `#!/bin/sh` will use `dash`.

On my Debian 7, `zsh` also does not expand the sequence.  (I checked ksh, bash, dash and zsh).

Comment: dash is `/bin/sh` on Debian and kids, but not the default shell for users - that is still bash. (And OP saying oh-my-zsh indicates their shell is zsh)

Comment: ```
➜  ~ bash -c "echo {a..z}"
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
➜  ~ dash -c "echo {a..z}"                              
{a..z}
```

Comment: I checked bash, and it works, Thank you very much. I love Linux.

Comment: For the record, `{1..10}` originates in `zsh` (also supporting `{00..03}`), `zsh` had `{a-z}` (with the `braceccl` option), not `{a..z}`. `ksh` later borrowed it and extended it with `{first..last[..incr][%fmt]}` and allowing some character ranges. `bash` copied a subset of ksh with some limitations/bugs. Eventually, `zsh` got the `{x..y..incr}` and character ranges (supporting any range). So, here the problem is that the OP is using too old a version of zsh.